# how to solve Post 400 error on bot framework emulator?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, azure, bots

i have used core bot framework template from Visual studio and created bot, then i did app registration on below url
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade
Then  Used Microsoft app Id and Microsoft password  on  "https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new"  link  to create  bot and added endpoint as https://113526c2.ngrok.io/api/messages 
Then used Microsoft App id and App password in c#.net code ,  configured  Microsoft App id and App password which get from app registartion  and  endpoint url as https://113526c2.ngrok.io/api/messages on bot framework emulator
But bot is not working on bot framework, why?, Post 400 error display on bot emulator 
How to solve it ?